# RecyclerView не показывает данные из Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase-database

Уже попробовал разные способы подключения Firebase database к RecyclerView, но каждый раз при запуске приложения он отказывается показывать картинки из хранилища. И при этом нет никаких ошибок, просто открывается пустой Activity. Как справится с этой проблемой? 
Структура данных в Firebase database (картинки передаются из Firebase storage)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код activity

```
public class SimpleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<GalleryGridObject> galleryList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DatabaseReference mRef;
private FirebaseDatabase database;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    //mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Data");
    mRef = database.getReference("Data");
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<GalleryGridObject> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<GalleryGridObject>()
                    .setQuery(mRef, GalleryGridObject.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<GalleryGridObject, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<GalleryGridObject, ViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull GalleryGridObject model) {
                    Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.imageGallery);
                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.item_coupons, viewGroup, false);

                    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
                }
            };

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}
}
```

Модель для RecyclerView GalleryGridObject

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
```

public class GalleryGridObject {

```
String image;

public GalleryGridObject () {
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
}

public GalleryGridObject(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
}
```

ViewHolder для RecyclerView

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public ImageView imageGallery;

public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    imageGallery = itemView.findViewById(R.id.coupons_picture);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ну вот смотрю на ваш код и возникает вопрос.

Вот здесь вы создали массив(List), но вы не добавляете нигде в коде, данные в этот массив. А затем вы хотите получить данные от этого пустого массива.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Качестве ответа могу показать пример:

```
    private List<String> list_img = new ArrayList<String>();
    private DatabaseReference mRef;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference();

    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("Data").getChildren()){
                list_img.add(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("Data").child(ds.getKey()).getValue()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: galleryList остался от предыдущего способа, но в моем коде он нигде не используется, вместо него я использую GalleryGridObject.class

Comment: В вашем примере используется String вместо кастомного массива, а как с ним создать адаптер, если нет getting и setting  для, например, подключения Picasso (метод getImage()) - (Picasso.get().load(galleryList.getImage()).into(holder.imageGallery);

Comment: использовал ваш способ, но теперь появился в RecyclerView только 1 CardView, и то он полностью пустой

Answer (score 0):

Надо изменить `private ArrayList<GalleryGridObject> galleryList = new ArrayList<>();`
на `private List<GalleryGridObject> galleryList;` В итоге код фрагмента (или активити) должен получиться таким

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

private List<GalleryGridObject> galleryList;
private TestAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DatabaseReference mRef;
private FirebaseDatabase database;

public TestFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_coupons, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    galleryList = new ArrayList<>();

    mAdapter = new TestAdapter(galleryList);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    //mRef = database.getReference().child("Data");
    mRef = database.getReference("Data");

    mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            GalleryGridObject image = dataSnapshot.getValue(GalleryGridObject.class);
            galleryList.add(image);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}

public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private Context mContext;
    private List<GalleryGridObject> galleryArrayList;

    public TestAdapter( List<GalleryGridObject> galleryArrayList){
        //this.mContext=mContext;
        this.galleryArrayList=galleryArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TestAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_coupons, parent, false);

        return new TestAdapter.ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TestAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //GalleryGridObject gallery = galleryArrayList.get(position);
        //Glide.with(mContext).load(galleryArrayList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.imageGallery);
        holder.textView.setText(galleryArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
        Picasso.get().load(galleryArrayList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.imageGallery);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(galleryArrayList==null) return 0;
        return galleryArrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imageGallery;
        public TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            imageGallery = itemView.findViewById(R.id.coupons_picture);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.coupons_title);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Вот модель для RecyclerView (обязательно нужен пустой конструктор)

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class GalleryGridObject {

String title, image;

public GalleryGridObject () {
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
}

public GalleryGridObject(String title, String image) {
    this.title = title;
    this.image = image;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
}
```